# custom validator not recognized in flask_wtf

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-wtforms

I have this Registrationform

```
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField("username", validators=[InputRequired(), Length(min=4, max=7, message="must be between 4 and 7 Chars long")])
    email = StringField("Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    password_repeat = PasswordField('repeat Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('sign Up')

    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('username allready taken.')

    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user is not None:
            raise ValidationError('email already taken.')

    def validate_name(form, username):
        if 't' in username.data:
            raise ValidationError('no t pls')
```

I want to build a custom Validator to check for example if the entered username contains the letter "t"
if so display an `ValidationError`

```
 def validate_name(form, username):
        if 't' in username.data:
            raise ValidationError('no t pls')
```

if I understood the docs correctly on [Custom validators](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html)

the syntax should be correct, but I get no Error message when inserting and submitting the data

I use `if form.validate_on_submit():`  in `routes`

Comment: You don't have a form field `name` so the validator `validate_name` will never be called - or is that just a typo?

Answer (score -1):

```
def validate_name(form, username):
    if 't' in username.data:
        raise ValidationError('no t pls')
```

Instead of form, you have to pass in `self`.

```
def validate_name(self, username):
    if 't' in username.data:
        raise ValidationError('no t pls')
```